What if I start ignoring my financial security in the US?
I am putting this here instead of Law SE because the community here is best suited to answer this IMO.
I have a long and good credit history established in the US.  I don't have a record of missing payments or anything like that.
I am a US citizen.  I live outside of the US and plan to for the indefinite future.  I receive letters / emails once in awhile telling me that my SSN and other personal info has been stolen, just like everyone else in the US.
What will happen if I ignore these alerts and my financial record in general in the US, while I'm not in the US?  I don't have a plan to come back any time soon.  Am I legally obliged to keep track of identity health, fraud, and data breaches?  If I don't pay attention and come back to the US in 10 years to find that there are several delinquent accounts in my name created by thieves and used while I was gone, am I responsible?

It might be smart to put a freeze on your credit, especially if you don't plan to use it to secure new loans in the US. It is really easy to do and free in the US. Basically it forces creditors to call you to do extra verification before opening new lines of credit and alerts creditors to be more cautious.

@JohnFx 4 agencies were frozen last I checked.  I don't know about now because they all seem to always forget my passcode, email, or something else so after a year or two they don't know my freeze number or password anymore, and I have to start the process to reset everything.


Am I legally obliged to keep track of identity health, fraud, and data breaches?

No, but if you ever do return to the US you might find a lot of creditors looking for you to pay your bills, and a large mess to clean up.

If I don't pay attention and come back to the US in 10 years to find that there are several delinquent accounts in my name created by thieves and used while I was gone, am I responsible?

This is much more a legal question. There are statutes of limitations that would be involved, but yes, you would have to defend yourself against any financial activity done using your identity. You would probably have a reasonable argument (not a legal opinion), but it still would be a hassle to deal with.
My unprofessional advice would be to close as many open accounts as you can and put a freeze on your credit report. That will make it much harder for someone else to use your identify to extend credit.

I honestly almost upvoted this without even reading it just based on the user.  Always helpful information from him.  Does closing accounts really help, since they use the information stolen to open new ones?

Thanks for that - I appreciate it :) It can't hurt to close accounts if you don't need them - for example someone could use your identity to put a charge on a retail credit card.  It's still unlikely but it can't hurt to lock up as much as you can.

You potentially still have several connections to the US financial system. Therefore you will be concerned about identity theft connected to your US identity.

US Federal and maybe state taxes. You are a US citizen. Therefore you will probably have to file a return. That means that if your identity is stolen, you could discover that you can't successfully file because somebody filed a fraudulent return before you did, or that their activity triggered income that you knew nothing about, and the IRS will expect to see on your return.
Social security. If you worked enough years in the US you could qualify for benefits
IRA's and 401(k). You want to protect those balances.

You will be expecting those accounts to be there when you need them. You might think I will be able to monitor them from outside the US, but some people forget to check their balance for years.
